# Access inner class instance from an outer class instance that was used for the inner instance creation

Tags: java

Suppose that I had a class *"Outer"* that holds class *"Inner"* as nested non static class.

Suppose that in `main()` I created instance of *"Outer"* class named *"a"*.
Suppose that I used *"a"* to create an *"Inner"* instance named *"in"*.

**my question is:** How can I reach the variables of instance "in", which is supposedly part of "a", from object "a"?

below is an example from:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-synthetic

I tried to play with it but it seems to overrun my private string field. I tried to set the string of the Inner instance and than get it - but all I get is null.

```
public class Synthetic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SyntheticMethodDemo a = new SyntheticMethodDemo();
        SyntheticMethodDemo.NestedClass in = a.new NestedClass();
        a.setNestedField("hello");
        System.out.println(a.getNestedField());
    }
} //this is my addition

class SyntheticMethodDemo {
    class NestedClass {
        private String nestedField;
    }

    public String getNestedField() {
        return new NestedClass().nestedField;
    }

    public void setNestedField(String nestedField) {
        new NestedClass().nestedField = nestedField;
    }
} //this is the code from the site
```

I would expect to get hello as a result of running main(), but I get "null"
instead

Comment: @D.Khumoyun: Please stop making edits where you boldface pieces of text. It detracts rather than improves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it you want to be able to get access to the inner class's fields via an instance of the outer class that contains it.  You can do that by saving a reference to the inner class in the outer class as so.

```java
public class Synthetic {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SyntheticMethodDemo a = new SyntheticMethodDemo();
      SyntheticMethodDemo.NestedClass in = a.new NestedClass();
      a.setNestedField("Hello");
      System.out.println(a.getNestedField());
   } // this is my addition
}

class SyntheticMethodDemo {
   NestedClass nc;

   class NestedClass {
      private String nestedField;

      NestedClass() {
         nc = this;
      }
   }

   public String getNestedField() {
      return nc.nestedField;
   }

   public void setNestedField(String nestedField) {
      nc.nestedField = nestedField;
   }
} // this is the code from the site
```

I believe your problem is that there is a one to one correspondence with the inner and outer class that you can't get rid of.  You can always create any number of independent inner classes from a single outer instance.  But when you try to access them from the `outer instance`, that `instance` has no idea which `inner instance` you want.  So you would have to `save` all the inner instances in a `map` or some other `data structure` and specify an `id` to get the correct inner instance.

This is easily done but I am not certain as to the benefit.

Comment: Thanks @WJS !! This is exactly the answer I was looking for! You are right: I did have a 1 to 1 correspondence WRONG understanding of the situation. Obviously I can create many Inner instants with a single Outer instance - but I did not grasp the full meaning of it until now. Very well explained :-). 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your getter and setter of `SyntheticMethodDemo` you always create a new instance of the inner class `NestedClass`, manipulate or retrieve the value of `nestedField` but never store the reference to the `NestedClass` instance. From that point the example from Baeldung is useless and misleading.

I adjusted the example to make it store an instance of the nested class which should make your code behave as you expected:

```
class SyntheticMethodDemo {
    class NestedClass {
        private String nestedField;
    }

    private final NestedClass nested = new NestedClass();

    public String getNestedField() {
        return nested.nestedField;
    }

    public void setNestedField(String nestedField) {
        nested.nestedField = nestedField;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation Arne!  My question is more with regard to the explanation before the code and about the code that is within main. In the corrected example you provided, it does not seem that i get the privates of instance "in" through instance "a". What puzzles me is that although "in" is dependent on "a", I do not seem to find a way to get into "in"'s private string by using "a"